# Example of strongly continuous function $u$ that is not weakly continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

Can you give me an example of a strongly continuous function  $u: X \to \mathbb{R}$, where $X$ is a Banach space, that is not weakly continuous?

Comment: Can you tell the difference between the definitions of strong and weak continuities ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, but I cannot find an explicit example.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest example is $x \mapsto \|x\|_X$.

Comment: I can see that if $X$ has a Schauder  base $e_n$ of norm 1 elements (like most "standard" Banach spaces), then $e_n \to 0$ weakly, but not not in norm. What is the general argument? Maybe expand your answer?

Comment: Why is this an example?

Comment: If $x \mapsto \|x\|_X$ would be weakly continuous, the set $\{ x \in X \mid \|x \| < 1\}$ would be weakly open, which cannot happen (unless $X$ is finite dimensional). Beware, however, that the norm is weakly sequentially continuous in $\ell^1$ (due to Schur's theorem).